# Book on Noahides by Sefardi Chief Rabbi

Tags: product-recommendation, gentiles, jewish-books, noahidism, sephardim

I heard from someone that there is a book on Noahides written by the Sefardi Chief Rabbi. But, I couldn't find it.

Does anyone know of this book, if it exists and which book it is?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elijah_Benamozegh

Comment: There is also a book from Rabbi Ory shriki

Comment: @kouty yes Brit Shalom by R Oury Cherki https://www.amazon.com/dp/1716811724/ref=cm_sw_em_r_mt_dp_7Q378P2911W7ET0DC50M, he is Sefardi but he is not (yet?) Chief Rabbi

Comment: By the way I don't think the Sefardi Chief Rabbi (or the last one) wrote such a book. Pretty sure. So it might be a confusion with another Sefardi Rabbi, maybe Brit Shalom that kouty first mentioned